# How to I bind knockout with webapi

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me the difference between the following two RateCardViewModel functions

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    ko.applyBindings(new RateCardsViewModel(1));
});

function RateCardsViewModel(projectId) {  //This version binds as expected
    var self = this;
    self.rateCards = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON("/api/mydata/1", self.rateCards);
}

function RateCardsViewModel(projectId) {   //This version does not bind
    var self = this;
    self.rateCards = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("/api/mydata/1", function (data) {
        self.rateCards = data;
    });
```

}

It looks like the second version is getting its data after the bind, but I thought both versions of getJSON were async.  Any help would be appreciated.

I need to do this the second way because I want to use the mapping plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both version are getting the data asynchronously. The difference is that the first version is passing the data retrieved immediately to the observable, while the other provides a custom function which in turn replaces the observable.

Do not, however, forget that an observable is actually a function, which means that when you set the value of an observable you should use `self.rateCards(newValue)` not `self.rateCards = newValue`. In the latter case you would actually replace the observable, not update it's value, meaning that no subscriptions to the observable would know about the change and would still be subscribed to the now non-used observable object.

To replace the top version, you should therefore do something like:

```
function RateCardsViewModel(projectId) {
    var self = this;
    self.rateCards = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("/api/mydata/1", function (data) {
        self.rateCards(data);
    });
}
```